# Cannot get ggplot2 to show a trendline by month

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, facet, trendline

I am trying to plot trendlines for my data by month and visualize them on a faceted ggplot. R is not allowing me to show the trendline. I want to use `geom_line()` or `geom_smooth()`. I have a hypothesis about why this is happening, I am assuming it's because ggplot is viewing the Month names as categorical (factors), seeing as my code otherwise seems to match online tutorials for showing points and lines on the same faceted ggplot.

I tried using month.name, to convert my month names to recognizable months to test my hypothesis, but R does this incorrectly (May, July, and September were converted to April, February, and June?).

I also have the plots mainly displaying as I want, for example yields the following:

```
Toledo_month_log_cyano %>% ggplot(aes(x=Month, y = `Log GC/L`)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = gene)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~gene, ncol = 1)
```

[image: Plot from code]

It looks mainly how I want, I just want a trend line which doesn't show. If someone could help me figure out what the problem is and solve it that would be great!

Comment: Add `group = gene` inside `aes`

Comment: THANK YOU I really appreciate it! This fixed the problem. With ggplot it's always something so simple that I am forgetting, and I stare at it for way too long.